# How to Modify XML File using Powershell

Tags: powershell

Hi Friends i want to modify some Text value in `<Option Name="Activate">1</Option>` to `<Option Name="Activate">0</Option>`. I am unable to locate node value `<Option Name="Activate">1</Option>` using powershell. below is the full code section in which i want to modify the Text. Please help.

```
<User Name="Richard">
        <Option Name="Pass">b56e0b4ea4962283bee762525c2d490f</Option>
        <Option Name="Containers">MasterVal</Option>
        <Option Name="Max Limit Allowed">2</Option>
        <Option Name="Limit Allowed">0</Option>
        <Option Name="User Limit">0</Option>
        <Option Name="Activate">1</Option>
        <Option Name="Feedback"></Option>
        <Option Name="ForceSsl">2</Option>
        <FileAllowed>
            <Disallowed />
            <Allowed />
        </FileAllowed>
        <Authorizations />
        <SpeedLimits DlType="0" DlLimit="10" ServerDlLimitBypass="2" UlType="0" UlLimit="10" ServerUlLimitBypass="2">
            <Download />
            <Upload />
        </SpeedLimits>
    </User>
```

[Download XML File Here](http://www.filedropper.com/bookstore)

So far i have tried Below Code but unable to complete. :(

```
$xml = New-Object XML
$XML.Load("D:\PSScript\BookStore.xml")
$xml.bookstore.Users.user |
Where-Object { ($_.Name -eq 'Richard')} |
Select-Object -Property Option
```

**Note : I want to use a condition here for example i want to change 1 Tag text value only for specific user, In short i want to modify text based on user id, Like where name = Richard change its `<Option Name="Activate">1</Option>` to `<Option Name="Activate">0</Option>` **

`<BookStore>`
`<Settings>`
`<Item name="Admin port" type="numeric">88881</Item>`
`</Settings>`
`<Container>`
`<Containers Name="MasterVal">`
`<Option Name="Max Limit Allowed">0</Option>`
`<Option Name="Limit Allowed">0</Option>`
`<Option Name="User Limit">0</Option>`
`<Option Name="Activate">1</Option>`
`<Option Name="Feedback">`
`</Option>`
`<Option Name="ForceSsl">0</Option>`
`<FileAllowed>`
`<Disallowed />`
`<Allowed />`
`</FileAllowed>`
`<Authorizations>`
`<Authorization path="E:\BookMaster\RootFolder">`
`<Option Name="FileRead">1</Option>`
`<Option Name="FileWrite">0</Option>`
`<Option Name="FileDelete">0</Option>`
`<Option Name="FileAppend">0</Option>`
`<Option Name="pathCreate">0</Option>`
`<Option Name="pathDelete">0</Option>`
`<Option Name="pathList">1</Option>`
`<Option Name="pathSubdirs">1</Option>`
`<Option Name="IsHome">1</Option>`
`<Option Name="AutoCreate">0</Option>`
`</Authorization>`
`<Authorization path="E:\BookMaster\RootFolder\MST\reports">`
`<Option Name="FileRead">1</Option>`
`<Option Name="FileWrite">1</Option>`
`<Option Name="FileDelete">1</Option>`
`<Option Name="FileAppend">1</Option>`
          `<Option Name="pathCreate">1</Option>`
         `<Option Name="pathDelete">0</Option>`
        `<Option Name="pathList">1</Option>`
       `<Option Name="pathSubdirs">1</Option>`
      `<Option Name="IsHome">0</Option>`
     `<Option Name="AutoCreate">0</Option>`
    `</Authorization>`
   `<Authorization path="E:\BookMaster\RootFolder\MST\NT">`
  `<Option Name="FileRead">1</Option>`
 `<Option Name="FileWrite">1</Option>`
`<Option Name="FileDelete">1</Option>`
          `<Option Name="FileAppend">1</Option>`
         `<Option Name="pathCreate">1</Option>`
        `<Option Name="pathDelete">0</Option>`
       `<Option Name="pathList">1</Option>`
      `<Option Name="pathSubdirs">1</Option>`
     `<Option Name="IsHome">0</Option>`
    `<Option Name="AutoCreate">0</Option>`
   `</Authorization>`
  `<Authorization path="E:\BookMaster\RootFolder\MST\WIN">`
 `<Option Name="FileRead">1</Option>`
`<Option Name="FileWrite">1</Option>`
          `<Option Name="FileDelete">1</Option>`
         `<Option Name="FileAppend">1</Option>`
        `<Option Name="pathCreate">1</Option>`
       `<Option Name="pathDelete">0</Option>`
      `<Option Name="pathList">1</Option>`
     `<Option Name="pathSubdirs">1</Option>`
    `<Option Name="IsHome">0</Option>`
   `<Option Name="AutoCreate">0</Option>`
  `</Authorization>`
 `<Authorization path="E:\BookMaster\RootFolder\MST\Winsxs">`
`<Option Name="FileRead">1</Option>`
          `<Option Name="FileWrite">1</Option>`
         `<Option Name="FileDelete">1</Option>`
        `<Option Name="FileAppend">1</Option>`
       `<Option Name="pathCreate">1</Option>`
      `<Option Name="pathDelete">0</Option>`
     `<Option Name="pathList">1</Option>`
    `<Option Name="pathSubdirs">1</Option>`
   `<Option Name="IsHome">0</Option>`
  `<Option Name="AutoCreate">0</Option>`
 `</Authorization>`
`<Authorization path="E:\BookMaster\RootFolder\SXS">`
          `<Option Name="FileRead">1</Option>`
         `<Option Name="FileWrite">1</Option>`
        `<Option Name="FileDelete">1</Option>`
       `<Option Name="FileAppend">1</Option>`
      `<Option Name="pathCreate">1</Option>`
     `<Option Name="pathDelete">0</Option>`
    `<Option Name="pathList">1</Option>`
   `<Option Name="pathSubdirs">1</Option>`
  `<Option Name="IsHome">0</Option>`
 `<Option Name="AutoCreate">1</Option>`
`</Authorization>`
      `</Authorizations>`
     `<SpeedLimits DlType="1" DlLimit="10" ServerDlLimitBypass="0" UlType="1" UlLimit="10" ServerUlLimitBypass="0">`
    `<Download />`
   `<Upload />`
  `</SpeedLimits>`
 `</Containers>`
`<Containers Name="DMPL(9990)-D">`
      `<Option Name="Max Limit Allowed">0</Option>`
     `<Option Name="Limit Allowed">0</Option>`
    `<Option Name="User Limit">0</Option>`
   `<Option Name="Activate">1</Option>`
  `<Option Name="Feedback">`
 `</Option>`
`<Option Name="ForceSsl">0</Option>`
      `<FileAllowed>`
     `<Disallowed />`
    `<Allowed />`
   `</FileAllowed>`
  `<Authorizations>`
 `<Authorization path="E:\BookMaster\RootFolder\MST">`
`<Option Name="FileRead">1</Option>`
          `<Option Name="FileWrite">0</Option>`
         `<Option Name="FileDelete">0</Option>`
        `<Option Name="FileAppend">0</Option>`
       `<Option Name="pathCreate">0</Option>`
      `<Option Name="pathDelete">0</Option>`
     `<Option Name="pathList">1</Option>`
    `<Option Name="pathSubdirs">1</Option>`
   `<Option Name="IsHome">1</Option>`
  `<Option Name="AutoCreate">0</Option>`
 `</Authorization>`
`<Authorization path="E:\BookMaster\RootFolder\MST\NT\Report_9990">`
          `<Option Name="FileRead">1</Option>`
         `<Option Name="FileWrite">1</Option>`
        `<Option Name="FileDelete">1</Option>`
       `<Option Name="FileAppend">1</Option>`
      `<Option Name="pathCreate">0</Option>`
     `<Option Name="pathDelete">0</Option>`
    `<Option Name="pathList">1</Option>`
   `<Option Name="pathSubdirs">1</Option>`
  `<Option Name="IsHome">0</Option>`
 `<Option Name="AutoCreate">0</Option>`
`</Authorization>`
      `</Authorizations>`
     `<SpeedLimits DlType="1" DlLimit="10" ServerDlLimitBypass="0" UlType="1" UlLimit="10" ServerUlLimitBypass="0">`
    `<Download />`
   `<Upload />`
  `</SpeedLimits>`
 `</Containers>`
`</Container>`
  `<Users>`
 `<User Name="leonardo">`
`<Option Name="Pass">05538eb07b4dbf66b1da4ea9374ac8f5</Option>`
      `<Option Name="Containers">MasterVal</Option>`
     `<Option Name="Max Limit Allowed">2</Option>`
    `<Option Name="Limit Allowed">0</Option>`
   `<Option Name="User Limit">0</Option>`
  `<Option Name="Activate">1</Option>`
 `<Option Name="Feedback">`
`</Option>`
      `<Option Name="ForceSsl">2</Option>`
     `<FileAllowed>`
    `<Disallowed />`
   `<Allowed />`
  `</FileAllowed>`
 `<Authorizations />`
`<SpeedLimits DlType="0" DlLimit="10" ServerDlLimitBypass="2" UlType="0" UlLimit="10" ServerUlLimitBypass="2">`
       `<Download />`
      `<Upload />`
     `</SpeedLimits>`
    `</User>`
   `<User Name="repturet">`
  `<Option Name="Pass">e076fc6c4c8a245beec106646719f738</Option>`
 `<Option Name="Containers">`
`</Option>`
      `<Option Name="Max Limit Allowed">0</Option>`
     `<Option Name="Limit Allowed">0</Option>`
    `<Option Name="User Limit">0</Option>`
   `<Option Name="Activate">1</Option>`
  `<Option Name="Feedback">`
 `</Option>`
`<Option Name="ForceSsl">0</Option>`
      `<FileAllowed>`
     `<Disallowed />`
    `<Allowed />`
   `</FileAllowed>`
  `<Authorizations>`
 `<Authorization path="E:\BookMaster\RootFolder\MST\NT">`
`<Option Name="FileRead">1</Option>`
          `<Option Name="FileWrite">1</Option>`
         `<Option Name="FileDelete">0</Option>`
        `<Option Name="FileAppend">1</Option>`
       `<Option Name="pathCreate">0</Option>`
      `<Option Name="pathDelete">0</Option>`
     `<Option Name="pathList">1</Option>`
    `<Option Name="pathSubdirs">1</Option>`
   `<Option Name="IsHome">0</Option>`
  `<Option Name="AutoCreate">0</Option>`
 `</Authorization>`
`<Authorization path="E:\BookMaster\RootFolder\MST">`
          `<Option Name="FileRead">1</Option>`
         `<Option Name="FileWrite">0</Option>`
        `<Option Name="FileDelete">0</Option>`
       `<Option Name="FileAppend">0</Option>`
      `<Option Name="pathCreate">0</Option>`
     `<Option Name="pathDelete">0</Option>`
    `<Option Name="pathList">1</Option>`
   `<Option Name="pathSubdirs">1</Option>`
  `<Option Name="IsHome">1</Option>`
 `<Option Name="AutoCreate">0</Option>`
`</Authorization>`
      `</Authorizations>`
     `<SpeedLimits DlType="0" DlLimit="10" ServerDlLimitBypass="0" UlType="0" UlLimit="10" ServerUlLimitBypass="0">`
    `<Download />`
   `<Upload />`
  `</SpeedLimits>`
 `</User>`
`<User Name="Anuj">`
     `<Option Name="Pass">270a8eaf5877a08bc69bdde947f8e8b6</Option>`
    `<Option Name="Containers">DMPL(9990)-D</Option>`
   `<Option Name="Max Limit Allowed">2</Option>`
  `<Option Name="Limit Allowed">0</Option>`
 `<Option Name="User Limit">0</Option>`
`<Option Name="Activate">1</Option>`
      `<Option Name="Feedback">`
     `</Option>`
    `<Option Name="ForceSsl">2</Option>`
   `<FileAllowed>`
  `<Disallowed />`
 `<Allowed />`
`</FileAllowed>`
      `<Authorizations />`
     `<SpeedLimits DlType="0" DlLimit="10" ServerDlLimitBypass="2" UlType="0" UlLimit="10" ServerUlLimitBypass="2">`
    `<Download />`
   `<Upload />`
  `</SpeedLimits>`
 `</User>`
`<User Name="pallavi">`
   `<Option Name="Pass">8d644bb6af9f1822de1d668d0ea6c36a</Option>`
  `<Option Name="Containers">MasterVal</Option>`
 `<Option Name="Max Limit Allowed">2</Option>`
`<Option Name="Limit Allowed">0</Option>`
     `<Option Name="User Limit">0</Option>`
    `<Option Name="Activate">1</Option>`
   `<Option Name="Feedback">`
  `</Option>`
 `<Option Name="ForceSsl">2</Option>`
`<FileAllowed>`
    `<Disallowed />`
   `<Allowed />`
  `</FileAllowed>`
 `<Authorizations />`
`<SpeedLimits DlType="0" DlLimit="10" ServerDlLimitBypass="2" UlType="0" UlLimit="10" ServerUlLimitBypass="2">`
        `<Download />`
   `<Upload />`
  `</SpeedLimits>`
 `</User>`
`<User Name="piyush">`
      `<Option Name="Pass">db699a999e4a6c8bd867720850d3007c</Option>`
      `<Option Name="Containers">MasterVal</Option>`
      `<Option Name="Max Limit Allowed">2</Option>`
      `<Option Name="Limit Allowed">0</Option>`
     `<Option Name="User Limit">0</Option>`
    `<Option Name="Activate">1</Option>`
   `<Option Name="Feedback">`
  `</Option>`
 `<Option Name="ForceSsl">2</Option>`
`<FileAllowed>`
        `<Disallowed />`
       `<Allowed />`
      `</FileAllowed>`
     `<Authorizations />`
    `<SpeedLimits DlType="0" DlLimit="10" ServerDlLimitBypass="2" UlType="0" UlLimit="10" ServerUlLimitBypass="2">`
   `<Download />`
  `<Upload />`
 `</SpeedLimits>`
 `</User>`
`<User Name="Richard">`
`<Option Name="Pass">b56e0b4ea4962283bee762525c2d490f</Option>`
`<Option Name="Containers">MasterVal</Option>`
`<Option Name="Max Limit Allowed">2</Option>`
`<Option Name="Limit Allowed">0</Option>`
`<Option Name="User Limit">0</Option>`
`<Option Name="Activate">1</Option>`
`<Option Name="Feedback">`
`</Option>`
`<Option Name="ForceSsl">2</Option>`
`<FileAllowed>`
`<Disallowed />`
`<Allowed />`
`</FileAllowed>`
`<Authorizations />`
`<SpeedLimits DlType="0" DlLimit="10" ServerDlLimitBypass="2" UlType="0" UlLimit="10" ServerUlLimitBypass="2">`
`<Download />`
`<Upload />`
`</SpeedLimits>`
`</User>`
`</Users>`
`</BookStore>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main problem is you need to treat option elements as arrays. I copied your xml snippet to a file called test.xml and this code works (I'll explain how I parsed through your xml file at each step to show where Option is displaying as an array):

```powershell
[xml] $info = Get-Content test.xml #Shorthand for New-Object..Load
#This command isn't necessary but is helpful when looking for an attribute
$info | Format-List *

#From above command saw that $info.User is the base document element
$info.User
#showed Attribute in Option
$info.User.Option
#displayed an array element with Attribute as the 5 (6th cause you start at 0) index
$info.User.Option[5]
#displayed Name and #text attributes with #text = 1
$info.User.Option[5].'#text' = "0"
#updated #text attribute to 0
```

From this you should be able to modify your script to work with the full xml file.

As your still having problems, a better solution would be to adjust your xml so you can access each user as a full object rather then parsing through attributes:

```xml
     <User>
         <name>Richard</name>
         <pass>b56e0b4ea4962283bee762525c2d490f</pass>
         <containers>MasterVal</containers>
         <maxLimit>2</maxLimit>
         <minLimit>0</minLimit>
         <userLimit>0</userLimit>
         <activate>1</activate>
         <feedback></feedback>
         <forceSsl>2</forceSsl>
         <FileAllowed>
             <Disallowed />
             <Allowed />
         </FileAllowed>
         <Authorizations />
         <SpeedLimits DlType="0" DlLimit="10" ServerDlLimitBypass="2" UlType="0"
     UlLimit="10" ServerUlLimitBypass="2">
             <Download />
             <Upload />
         </SpeedLimits>
     </User>
```

Then you can access each user as `$info.User.Richard` and change each activate tags using `$info.User.Richard.activate = 0`. If you cannot do this you'll need to use foreach:

```powershell
[xml] $info = Get-Content test.xml
foreach ($i in $info.BookStore.Users.User) {
    if ($i.Name -eq "Richard") {
        foreach ($e in $i.Option) {
            if ($e.Name -eq "Activate") {
                $e.'#text' = "0"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then just write the xml back to the file. Note: Look at the use of select and select-xml if you want to simplify this later

Updated: with full answer given xml file

Comment: Sorry dear but its not working when i am trying this code for XML file which i have attached in the post. [link](http://www.filedropper.com/bookstore) . Could you please help me in this ?

Comment: Also i want to use a condition here for example i only wants to change <Option Name="Activate">1</Option> Tag text value only for specific user, In short i want to modify text based on user id

Comment: No, because my current firewall (working at school right now) doesn't allow access to filedropper.

Comment: is this link is ok please check or suggest any website which you can access, Thanks a lot for giving your precious time :)

[link](http://speedy.sh/4XRnm/BookStore.xml)

Comment: @Harsh I don't know about the link, the firewall blocks the entire site for some reason. Either way I updated my answer: take a look and see if that helps.

Comment: sorry mate i cannot modify this xml file as per my needs as it's automatically generates through a program, btw see post above, i have added whole text of XML file here. please suggest.

Comment: Done. and Sorry for bad formating. 

Can anybody help me to upload the XML file Here on this website ?

Comment: @Harsh see the final part of my answer (this works on my system)